# rvm config: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

When I run `rvm list`,it shows:

```
rvm rubies

=> /Users/ohho/.rvm/scripts/list: line 321: /Users/ohho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/config: No such file or directory
ruby-1.8.7-p371 [  ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Is it an error or can I just ignore it?

UPDATE

The error goes away after `rvm get stable` which updates `rvm 1.16.16` to `rvm 1.16.17`. A `config` file shows up in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/` after the rvm upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was a bug in generating config files in rvm 1.16.16 - it was solved already and updating rvm should be enough to fix it:

```
rvm get stable #or:
rvm get head
```

Comment: still getting this with rvm 1.17.0 stable with rbx-head on OSX ML

Answer (score -1):

It is not a critical error message; so you can ignore it.

However, the message is coming up most likely because the uninstall of `ruby-1.8.7-p371` version wasn't completed successfully.

Try running `rvm cleanup` - it might remove the stale folders.

You could go into `/Users/ohho/.rvm/rubies/` folder, and run `rm -rf ruby-1.8.7-p371` to remove the folder completely

Or, try removing it, and reinstall as follows:

```
rvm remove ruby-1.8.7-p371
rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p371
```

Comment: Same error message even after installing?! Weird. Any error messages while installing? If you don't need a 1.8.7 installation, then probably best to ignore it.

Comment: Message after a complete installation: Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that requires        2 patches just to be compiled on up to date linux system.
This may have known and unaccounted for security vulnerabilities.
Please consider upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3-286 which will have all of the latest security patches.
'rvm_codesign_identity' is not set, please set it in ~/.rvmrc

Comment: That message is ok; it's just a warning message to get people to move away from 1.8.7. Are you still seeing `/Users/ohho/.rvm/scripts/list: line 321: /Users/ohho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/config: No such file or directory
ruby-1.8.7-p371` when you run `rvm list`?

Comment: Please see UPDATE in question.